# need efficient restructuring of a complicated PHP assoc array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

In my data mining project, I'm given a complicated, huge multidemensional array of arrays that contains all the info I require, except that I have to perform a "fix" on it before I can process it.  I've written some code that takes care of the issue, but it's taking **way** too long for the huge amount of data I have to "fix," and I'm hoping someone can help me find a more efficient solution.

Essentially, the type of array I'm working with is first indexed by an integer, as any run-of-the-mill array would, i.e. `$x[0], $x[1], $x[2]`, except that each element is an associative array that contains key-pair values that I need (such as `$x[0]['item'], $x[0]['price']`), however one key is stored a bit deeper, the ID.

An ID number exists in the array as `$x[0]['@attributes']['id']`, and I would like to simplify the structure by duplicating this info along with the other key pairs, like `$x[0]['id']`.

The data set I'm working with is large, but here is a simplified example of my situation:

```
$attrib1 = array('id'=>'101');
$item1 = array('@attributes'=>$attrib1, 'item'=>'milk', 'price'=>'3.50');
$attrib2 = array('id'=>'102');
$item2 = array('@attributes'=>$attrib2, 'item'=>'butter', 'price'=>'2.45');
$attrib3 = array('id'=>'103');
$item3 = array('@attributes'=>$attrib3, 'item'=>'bread', 'price'=>'1.19');
$items = array($item1, $item2, $item3);
echo "Starting data - items using itemid as attribute:\n";
print_r($items);

# set item numbers by key instead of attribute
$i=0;
while(isset($items[$i]['@attributes']['id'])) {
   $items[$i]['itemid'] = $items[$i]['@attributes']['id'];
   #unset($items[$i]['@attributes']);
   $i++;
} # while
echo "\nDesired result - items using itemid as key:\n";
print_r($items);
```

Here is the output from that above example:

```
Starting data - items using itemid as attribute:
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 101
                )

            [item] => milk
            [price] => 3.50
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 102
                )

            [item] => butter
            [price] => 2.45
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 103
                )

            [item] => bread
            [price] => 1.19
        )

)

Desired result - items using itemid as key:
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 101
                )

            [item] => milk
            [price] => 3.50
            [itemid] => 101
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 102
                )

            [item] => butter
            [price] => 2.45
            [itemid] => 102
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 103
                )

            [item] => bread
            [price] => 1.19
            [itemid] => 103
        )

)
```

Note the added [itemid] key-value pair in the desired result.  Is there a faster / more elegant way of accomplishing this?  I've looked at some of PHP's fancy array functions, but I can't wrap my head around this more complicated situation to make use of them.  Any ideas?

Comment: How many arrays are we talking about? Have you considered that parallel execution might be required for large amounts of data?

Comment: The arrays can contain as many as 300 to 4000 elements, each element containing a variety of associative key data, similar to my example data.  The trouble is, there are tens of thousands of these array sets I have to process, so even cutting out a few seconds for each one could potentially cut the full job by hours.

Answer (score 2):

#### Memory Efficiency

[PHP DOC Comments](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splfixedarray.php) : Memory footprint of `splFixedArray` is about `37%` of a regular "array" of the same size.

`splFixedArray` also implements `Iterator` which means it encapsulate the list and expose visibility to one element at a time making them far more efficient.

The `foreach` loop makes a copy of any array passed to it. If you are processing a large amount of data, using it directly with our array can be a performance issue

[Also see How big are PHP arrays (and values) really? (Hint: BIG!)](http://nikic.github.com/2011/12/12/How-big-are-PHP-arrays-really-Hint-BIG.html)

You can try

```
$it = SplFixedArray::fromArray($items);
foreach ( $it as $value ) {
    // Play with big array
}
```

#### Speed

Here is a simple benchmark

```
set_time_limit(0);
echo "<pre>";

$total = 10000;
$item = array("milk","butter","bread");
$items = array();

// Generating Random Data
for($i = 0; $i < $total; $i ++) {
    $att = array('id' => $i);
    $items[] = array('@attributes' => $att,'item' => $item[$i % 3],'price' => mt_rand(100, 5000) / 100);
}
// Pure array no copy
function m1($array) {
    foreach ( $array as $k => $v ) {
        isset($v['@attributes']) and $array[$k]['id'] = $v['@attributes']['id'];
        unset($array[$k]['@attributes']);
    }
    return $array;
}

// Array clean copy
function m2($array) {
    $items = array();
    foreach ( $array as $k => $v ) {
        isset($v['@attributes']) and $items[$k]['id'] = $v['@attributes']['id'];
        $items[$k]['item'] = $v['item'];
        $items[$k]['price'] = $v['price'];
    }
    return $items;
}

// Array Iterator
function m3($array) {
    $it = new ArrayIterator($array);
    $items = array();
    foreach ( $it as $k => $v ) {
        isset($v['@attributes']) and $items[$k]['id'] = $v['@attributes']['id'];
        $items[$k]['item'] = $v['item'];
        $items[$k]['price'] = $v['price'];
    }
    return $items;
}

// SplFixedArray Array
function m4($array) {
    $it = SplFixedArray::fromArray($array);
    $items = array();
    foreach ( $it as $k => $v ) {
        isset($v['@attributes']) and $items[$k]['id'] = $v['@attributes']['id'];
        $items[$k]['item'] = $v['item'];
        $items[$k]['price'] = $v['price'];
    }
    return $items;
}

// Array Map
function m5($array) {
    $items = array_map(function ($v) {
        isset($v['@attributes']) and $v['id'] = $v['@attributes']['id'];
        unset($v['@attributes']);
        return $v;
    }, $array);
    return $items;
}

// Array Walk
function m6($array) {
    array_walk($array, function (&$v, $k) {
        isset($v['@attributes']) and $v['id'] = $v['@attributes']['id'];
        unset($v['@attributes']);
        return $v;
    });
    return $array;
}

$result = array('m1' => 0,'m2' => 0,'m3' => 0,'m4' => 0,'m5' => 0,'m6' => 0);

for($i = 0; $i < 1; ++ $i) {
    foreach ( array_keys($result) as $key ) {
        $alpha = microtime(true);
        $key($items);
        $result[$key] += microtime(true) - $alpha;
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
echo "Single Run\n";
print_r($result);
echo '</pre>';

$result = array('m1' => 0,'m2' => 0,'m3' => 0,'m4' => 0,'m5' => 0,'m6' => 0);

for($i = 0; $i < 2; ++ $i) {
    foreach ( array_keys($result) as $key ) {
        $alpha = microtime(true);
        $key($items);
        $result[$key] += microtime(true) - $alpha;
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
echo "Dual Run\n";
print_r($result);
echo '</pre>';
```

***It has a very Interesting results***

**PHP 5.3.10**

```
Single Run
Array
(
    [m1] => 0.029280185699463 <--------------- fastest
    [m2] => 0.038463115692139
    [m3] => 0.049274921417236
    [m4] => 0.03856086730957
    [m5] => 0.032699823379517
    [m6] => 0.032186985015869
)

Dual Run
Array
(
    [m1] => 0.068470001220703
    [m2] => 0.077174663543701
    [m3] => 0.085768938064575
    [m4] => 0.07695198059082
    [m5] => 0.073209047317505
    [m6] => 0.065080165863037 <--------------- Fastest after in 2 loops
)
```

**PHP 5.4.1**

```
Single Run
Array
(
    [m1] => 0.029529094696045
    [m2] => 0.035377979278564
    [m3] => 0.03830099105835
    [m4] => 0.034613132476807
    [m5] => 0.031363010406494
    [m6] => 0.028403043746948  <---------- fastest
)

Dual Run
Array
(
    [m1] => 0.072367191314697
    [m2] => 0.071731090545654
    [m3] => 0.078131914138794
    [m4] => 0.075049877166748
    [m5] => 0.065959930419922
    [m6] => 0.060923099517822  <---------- Fastest
)
```

Comment: I want to test this, but codepad doesn't have SplFixedArray. Could you run [this test](http://codepad.org/vKp7Afwc) and report the results please?

Comment: It not new see http://nikic.github.com/2011/12/12/How-big-are-PHP-arrays-really-Hint-BIG.html

Comment: I see. Turns out it is almost twice as fast as the other answer http://codepad.viper-7.com/mvPm7w

Comment: You are looking at speed alone .. what of memory implications ???  It performs better in both :)

Comment: In my case, I have plenty of memory, so it's not so much of a factor.

Comment: Updated answer based on speed

Comment: Neat solution with the foreach and the isset/and code.  I tested that routine out with some live data, but it turned out to be much slower than my original code.  I could not implement the SplFixedArray with my live data, for some reason - it must be too large or complex. `Running [5] trials on method [Emo1 - original]...
Elapsed time: 0.12169504165649
Running [5] trials on method [Baba1a]...
Elapsed time: 0.6294641494751`

Comment: That is exactly what the speed test is all about .. you can see it was not the fastest solution ... look at the results again `array_walk` won the speed test

Comment: I tried 5 passes on live data, and m6() actually seems slower than m1() (shown in my previous comment) and are both slower than my original as follows: `Running [5] trials on method [Emo1 - original]...
Elapsed time: 0.12484383583069
Running [5] trials on method [Baba6]...
Elapsed time: 0.81396174430847`  Perhaps that walk function is being created/destroyed each iteration and slowing things down?

Comment: It depends on your implementation .. you can actually makes it much more slower .... am blind here .. don't know the data you are ruining on how how but have done my test

Comment: OK - it's looking like my benchmarking method is flawed.  When I reversed the order that I test the algorithms, I get different results.  Sorry about that.  Something is slowing down the operations as the script runs, so disregard my trial results up to this point - I'm going to look into it further.  Stay tuned.  :)

Comment: So, using Baba's script, I added my original routine and ran 50 trials (instead of 2). I've confirmed that m6() is slightly faster: `[m6] => 3.4863839149475 [Emo1] => 3.57093501091`  However, I'm still trying to figure out why the sample trial data I have behaves differently, so I'm looking into it further.

Comment: the more loop the more faster `m6` becomes .....

Answer (score 1):

That looks like it's coming from XML, so i would add that it's possible for @attributes to have more than just ID in it.. but assuming that won't happen you could try using a foreach instead, though I'm not sure about speed gains.

There may be an impact because you are modifying the same array you are looping (I can't find evidence for this though, so experiment required)

```
$cleanedArray = array();
foreach($bigArray as $subArray)
{
  if(isset($subArray['@attributes']))
  {
     $subArray['itemid'] = $subArray['@attributes']['id'];
    unset($subArray['@attributes']); //Optional
    $cleanedArray[] = $subArray;
  }
}
```

Apologies if that ends up *slower*

Edit: Missing index added

Comment: http://codepad.org/A8E9EfvR, seems faster by a pretty consistent ratio of 9 to 4, from my crude test

Comment: Seems like it's over twice as fast? I wasn't expecting that to be honest.. but good news!

Comment: Also thanks for that codepad link, never seen that before, looks useful.

Comment: Yes - the source data is XML - good eye.  The only thing stored as an attribute is that ID number.  I'll have to try this and other routines on some live data to see how they spec out - I'll post results.

Comment: BTW, your algorithm basically works, but you need $subArray['@attributes']['id'].  I tested my original and this one (no unsetting for either one), and I'm seeing this one to be much slower.

Comment: I'll edit answer, cheers

Comment: Here are the performance trials for this algorithm: `Running [5] trials on method [original (Emo)]...
Elapsed time: 0.12217831611633
Running [5] trials on method [Martin]...
Elapsed time: 0.51936292648315`

Comment: Interesting that your results differ so much from Asad's. But I'm not doubting either of them, platform etc can have big impact, the SPL solutions seem nice with documented benefits.

Comment: I am beginning to wonder why my results differ, myself - I'm using a my own benchmark script to test the methods, but using the full-featured test data.  I'm going to shift from that to using Baba's script and see if things differ on my platform.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer so much as it is a comparison of the approaches provided:

I used this script to average out the times the algorithms took:

```
<?php
//base data
$attrib1 = array('id'=>'101');
$item1 = array('@attributes'=>$attrib1, 'item'=>'milk', 'price'=>'3.50');
$attrib2 = array('id'=>'102');
$item2 = array('@attributes'=>$attrib2, 'item'=>'butter', 'price'=>'2.45');
$attrib3 = array('id'=>'103');
$item3 = array('@attributes'=>$attrib3, 'item'=>'bread', 'price'=>'1.19');
$results = array('test1'=>array(),'test2'=>array(),'test3'=>array());

//set trials
$trials=1000;

//test 1
for($count=0;$count<$trials;$count++){
unset($items);
$items = array($item1, $item2, $item3);
$timer1=microtime();
$i=0;
while(isset($items[$i]['@attributes']['id'])) {
   $items[$i]['itemid'] = $items[$i]['@attributes']['id'];
   $i++;
}
$timer1=microtime()-$timer1;
$results['test1'][$count]=$timer1;
}

//test 2
for($count=0;$count<$trials;$count++){
unset($items);
unset($cleanedArray);
$items = array($item1, $item2, $item3);
$cleanedArray = array();
$timer2=microtime();
foreach($items as $subArray)
{
  if(isset($subArray['@attributes']))
  {
    unset($subArray['@attributes']);
    $cleanedArray[] = $subArray;
  }
}
$timer2=microtime()-$timer2;
$results['test2'][$count]=$timer2;
}

//test 3
for($count=0;$count<$trials;$count++){
unset($items);
unset($it);
$items = array($item1, $item2, $item3);
$it = SplFixedArray::fromArray($items);
$timer3=microtime();
foreach($it as $subArray)
{
  if(isset($subArray['@attributes']))
  {
    unset($subArray['@attributes']);
    $cleanedArray[] = $subArray;
  }
}
$timer3=microtime()-$timer3;
$results['test3'][$count]=$timer3;
}

//results
$factor=pow(10,-6);
echo "Test 1 averaged " . round(array_sum($results['test1']) / count($results['test1'])/$factor,1) . " µs, with range: " . round((max($results['test1'])-min($results['test1']))/$factor,1) . " µs - (min: " . (min($results['test1'])/$factor) . ", max: " . (max($results['test1'])/$factor) . ")<br/>";

echo "Test 2 averaged " . round(array_sum($results['test2']) / count($results['test2'])/$factor,1) . " µs, with range: " . round((max($results['test2'])-min($results['test2']))/$factor,1) . " µs - (min: " . (min($results['test2'])/$factor) . ", max: " . (max($results['test2'])/$factor) . ")<br/>";

echo "Test 3 averaged " . round(array_sum($results['test3']) / count($results['test3'])/$factor,1) . " µs, with range: " . round((max($results['test3'])-min($results['test3']))/$factor,1) . " µs - (min: " . (min($results['test3'])/$factor) . ", max: " . (max($results['test3'])/$factor) . ")<br/>";

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($results);
echo "</pre>";
```

The results here are extremely variable at low numbers of trials, but should become more skewed if the base array is larger and larger numbers of trials are run.

Comment: My concern is not unsetting the unused data - I placed that code in my example to clean up the output for clarity in this posting.  My main focus is to quickly consolidate the ID in with the other associative data in the array.

Comment: @EmoMosley The repeated unsets are to make the tests fair. They are not timed. The gist of this code is to use each approach a large number of times and average the results.